# What is flush in print function?

Tags: python, printing, flush

What is *flush* in the **print** function in python? What happens if it is set *True*? In what cases setting it *True* helps? Please provide good examples to understand.
`print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

Answer (score 1):

It forces `print`'s output to the screen. In python 3 instead of doing this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

You can use `flush`.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function) for more details.